# Spoon: Empty adb logs in the report in Espresso tests

Tags: android, android-espresso, spoon, hockeyapp, spoon-gradle-plugin

I am getting no logs in the report. I am running Espresso Instrumented tests on multiple devices via Spoon. I have tried with version 1.4, 1.5.1 and 1.5.2 as well. No luck :(

java -jar spoon-runner-1.5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk hockeyapp-debug-unaligned.apk  --test-apk hockeyapp-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk --class-name Tests

Answer (score 0):

First, may I know what do you mean that you get no report? no report from Spoon, or no report on HockeyApp dashboard? Which kind of data are you collecting with HockeyApp SDK?

If the later, please provide more information, such as: How did you integration HockeyApp SDK? Did you set you the AppID in your app correctly? This [article](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk) could be helpful as how to integrate HockeyAPP SDK into an android app.

Please let me know if you have any further question concerning HockeyApp.

Comment: The context is w.r.t Spoon's test run report. I am getting the report but not getting the adb logs in the report. I have tried it with playstoreDebug build as well. I believe that eliminate its relation to hockey version of app.                  
Timestamp Level Tag Message

Comment: Can someone please help me here? I am still not getting the device logs in the report. :(

Comment: You can find a similar issue here: https://github.com/square/spoon/issues/252, and https://github.com/square/spoon/issues/251. Hopes it can give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is recently fixed as part of this [pull request](https://github.com/square/spoon/pull/354). You might want to switch to the latest version of spoon runner and check if it works.

Latest available version of spoon runner is 1.5.7 as of now where this issue was addressed.

By looking at the pull request, it looks like there was some issue with the **ddmlib** library on which this plugin depends upon to capture logs from device.

Hope this helps you.